# How to access iframe dom element in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two jsp pages and js files

```
one.jsp
two.jsp
one.js
two.js
```

one.js included in one.jsp, 
two.js included in two.jsp

two.jsp is loaded by iframe and inherited into one.jsp

My question is

I need to access one.jsp dom elements from two.js(One.js belongs to two.jsp(Iframe))

I tried this. but not working

```
var parentBody = window.parent.document.body
  console.log(parentBody.find("#tab1").html());
```

I tried this also from two.js

```
var x = window.parent.document.querySelector(".nav-tabs li:nth-child("+(numIframe+1)+")");
  x.parentNode.removeChild(x)
```

It is passing

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null
```

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: var parentBody = window.parent.document.body
  console.log(parentBody.find("#tab1").html());

Comment: `console.log($(parentBody).find("#tab1").html());` ?

Answer (score 0):

`find` is not a DOM method. It is a jQuery method.

You either need to use jQuery or use standard DOM.

```
console.log(window.parent.document.querySelector('#tab1').innerHTML)
```

Comment: It is getting iframe content. I need to get parent of iframe data, not in inframe

Comment: @Mohaideen — It gets the parent content when I test it. http://test-cases.dorward.me.uk/stackoverflow/33890722/parent.html

Comment: You are using tab1 content text for both. For me it is passing
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null

Comment: @Deen — In that demo (which you could have checked the source code of) I am copying the tab1 content text from one to the other using the code in my answer. Neither my code, nor the code in your question use `removeChild` so they can't be the cause of your problem you describe in your last comment.

Comment: @Deen — That just means that `".nav-tabs li:nth-child("+(numIframe+1)+")"` doesn't match anything in your parent document. Since we don't know what the HTML of your parent document looks like or what the value of `numIframe` is (or even if that value is a string or a number), that new question isn't currently answerable.